# GestureDetector Multi-touch

Tags: android, gesture, multi-touch

I'm working with touch gestures in Android using the `OnGestureListener` interface and `GestureDetector`.

I made an app to test if detecting two fingers works, in `onFlp(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,float velocityY)`, I print the id of the  different `MotionEvents` but these ids are the same (apparently only detects one finger).

Does `GestureDetector` support multi-touch events?

Comment: Does the mobile support multitouch?

Comment: Yes, but I cannot manage more than one fingers with this interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

**The Issue**

Using `OnGestureListener` to detect multitouch gestures does not seem to be implemented by default.

The first thing you may have tried is reading `event.pointerCount` to get the count of fingers on the screen. However, this will be equal to `1`. This is because you will (quite likely) never be able touch the screen with both fingers in exactly the same millisecond.

---

**Fixing it**

You have to buffer `pointerCount` (the amount of fingers on screen). First add those variables somewhere in the context that you intend to track gestures in:

```
// track how many fingers are used
var bufferedPointerCount = 1
var bufferTolerance = 500 // in ms
var pointerBufferTimer = Timer()
```

Then, in the `onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent)` function, you add this:

```
// Buffer / Debounce the pointer count
if (event.pointerCount > bufferedPointerCount) {
  bufferedPointerCount = event.pointerCount
  pointerBufferTimer = fixedRateTimer("pointerBufferTimer", true, bufferTolerance, 1000) {
    bufferedPointerCount = 1
    this.cancel() // a non-recurring timer
  }
}
```

Essentially this tracks the maximum amount of fingers on the display and keeps it valid for `bufferTolerance` milliseconds (here: 500).

---

*I currently am implementing it in a custom Android Launcher I created ([finnmglas/Launcher](https://github.com/finnmglas/Launcher) | see [related issue](https://github.com/finnmglas/Launcher/issues/52))*